Vitest fails when testing a typescript file
So I have a monorepo with a package called "types".
In this package I have installed vitest and I want to test this file:
src/marketplaces.ts
import { z } from 'zod';

export const marketplaces = z.enum([
  'unitedStates',
  'unitedKingdom'
]);

but just a basic test like this fails:
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import { marketplaces } from './marketplaces';
test('should work', () => {
  expect(marketplaces).toBeDefined();
});

with the error:

Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.

This is my vitest.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    include: ['src/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,ts}'],
  },
});


Are you sure you have TS installed? If you have it in your package.json try to run npm install again. For me the config works just fine.
